# Why isn’t executionTimeout updating for my SSM document step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I've been using AWS Systems Manager and have an SSM Automation Document that executes several steps using the `aws:runCommand` action.

However, one step fails with a 'Execution Timed Out' error.

Here's the step:

```yaml
- name: config_topology
  action: 'aws:runCommand'
  timeoutSeconds: 12800
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
    TimeoutSeconds: 12800
    Parameters:
      ...
```

Despite modifying the timeout value to 12800 seconds, the console continues to show it as the default 3600 seconds:

[image]

Comment: As you’re using Terraform (mentioned in a comment which crosses out using an older version of the doc), this really isn’t currently debuggable or reproducible // can you share something that we can use to reproduce? Your YAML looks fine.

Comment: Sorry I can't share more code, but you can still reproduce it, you just have to create a simple SSM Automation Document and try to change the executionTimeout not the timeoutSeconds (I guess it's something related to the Automation Document the normal one works fine)

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code you pasted looks good but you need to send the `executionTimeout` parameter inside "Parameters". Even with that, there is something else you need. What I have observed is that the `Execution Timeout` value is not affected by the configuration in your SSM Automation, but by the SSM Document itself. There is where you have to do the modification.

**SSM Document invoked by the automation**

```
---
schemaVersion: '2.2'
description: "Dummy description"
parameters:
  executionTimeout:
    type: String
    default: "7200"
    description: "Execution timeout"
mainSteps:
- action: aws:runShellScript
  name: whatever_process
  inputs:
    timeoutSeconds: "{{executionTimeout}}"
    runCommand: [
      "#!/bin/bash",
      ...
```

Note the parameter `timeoutSeconds` INSIDE the inputs in the mainSteps.

[ExecutionTimeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWhc4.png)